# Progress Bar is not filling in properly

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I want to make a simulation hack program because I'm bored. I want it to fill a progress bar, here's the method for that:

```
public void HackFrame() {
    double count = 0;
    outerloop:
    for(char i = '!'; i <= '~'; i++){
        for(char j = '!'; j <= '~'; j++){
            for(char k = '!'; k <= '~'; k++){
                count++;
                int completion = (int) ((count / 830584) * 100);
                System.out.println(completion);
                HackCompletion.setValue((int) completion);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I had `System.out.println(completion)` to make sure it would set values from 0 to 100. Which it does. The thing I don't understand is the progress bar. The only time it progresses is when I have
`System.out.println(completion);`. Literally every time I remove that, the bar is always filled. Is there a reason I don't know?

Here's my entire code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Hack {
    private String [] HackPhrases = {"Connecting to server. Sent control packet type is 7 (Outgoing-Call-Request)", "Validating user...", "Generating SHA-256 verification strings: 100%", "Validating blocks [1-512]: 512", "Connecting to game server. Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 19319)", "Establishing connection: 100%", "Connection successful on port 31337", "Downloading data: 100%", "Extracting data: 100%", "Calculating CRC values", "Packing data: 100%", "Injecting script. Sending 100%", "Checking server response...", "Generating Resources: 100%", "Generating Resources: Done", "Finalizing Process: 100%"};
    private JFrame Hack = new JFrame ();
    private JTextArea HackText = new JTextArea();
    private String Password = "~~~";
    private JProgressBar HackCompletion = new JProgressBar();
    public void makeFrame() {
        Hack.setSize(600, 400);
        Hack.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        HackText.setBounds(40, 20, 500, 200);
        HackText.setBackground(Color.black);
        HackCompletion.setBounds(140, 250, 300, 30);
        HackCompletion.setBackground(Color.green);
        HackCompletion.setForeground(Color.blue);
        Hack.add(HackCompletion);
        Hack.add(HackText);
        Hack.setLayout(null);
        Hack.setVisible(true);
        Hack.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void HackFrame() {
        double count = 0;
        outerloop:
        for(char i = '!'; i <= '~'; i++){
            for(char j = '!'; j <= '~'; j++){
                for(char k = '!'; k <= '~'; k++){
                    count++;
                    int completion = (int) ((count / 830584) * 100);
                    System.out.println(completion);
                    HackCompletion.setValue(completion);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Hack exampleHack = new Hack();
        exampleHack.makeFrame();
        exampleHack.HackFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: The progress bar is only painting when the loop finishes executing. If you want animation you need to use a Swing Timer to schedule the updates.

Comment: Thanks, but System.out.println(completion); fixes that?

Comment: System.out.println() executes in a separate Thread. So the looping logic will break every now and then to let other Threads execute which gives the GUI time to repaint. However without the System.out.println() your code is in a tight loop that finishes executing before the GUI has a chance to paint intermediate results.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: *"Here's my entire code:"* Don't post code at external sites and expect people to go there. That code is short enough to include in the question, and I have done that. **General tips:** *"Hack.setLayout(null);"* 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  ..

Comment: .. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).